# Waiting for html to render without the help of Selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I am aware that this question might have been asked before, but the answers provided have not helped me solve my problem.

Basically, I want to extract all of the listings from a rental website. I do not want to use selenium or any other headless browser libraries, as in my experience I have found them very slow and inconsistent. The link to the website is: https://www.huurstunt.nl/huren/eindhoven/

The problem with it is that it takes about a second to load the elements properly.

What I have tried so far:

```
def GetHuurstuntRentalHtml(city, page):
if page == 1:
    return requests.get(
        f"https://www.huurstunt.nl/huren/{city}/",
        headers = headers
    )
return requests.get(
    f"https://www.huurstunt.nl/huren/{city}/p{page}",
    headers = headers
)
```

This does not work at all because it doesn't do any waiting and the website's content is loaded by javascript.
What I found on another stackoverflow answer was to try using requests-html:

```
def GetHuurstuntRentalHtmlTest(city, page):
reqeust_session = HTMLSession()
if page == 1:
    listings_html = reqeust_session.get(
        f"https://www.huurstunt.nl/huren/{city}/"
    )
    listings_html.html.render(wait = 5)
    return listings_html
listings_html = reqeust_session.get(
    f"https://www.huurstunt.nl/huren/{city}/p{page}"
)
listings_html.html.render(wait = 5)
return listings_html
```

This does nothing different than the code snippet above. Is it possible to do this without using something like Selenium within python? I also want to deploy the application eventually, so that's also something I'd like to keep in mind. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `request-html` uses `pyppeteer` under the hood which is a browser automation tool that you just said you don't want to use.

Comment: really the only way to scrape info from a javascript rendered dynamic site is to try to discover their api and make requests to it, then you are typically no longer working with html and instead are parsing json data.  Otherwise browser automation tools/javascipt rendering engines are really the only other practical options.